# Unable to install wget on mac (mojave 10.14.6) result: Error: An exception occurred within a child process

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew, wget

I tried installing wget running this command line

```
brew install wget
```

The result:

```
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  CompilerSelectionError: libunistring cannot be built with any available compilers.
Install GNU's GCC:
  brew install gcc
```

I did that and then tried again, giving same error.

I also tried

```
sudo wget
```

and the result was

sudo: wget: command not found

which means wget was not installed. Can anyone recommend a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is requesting that you install "gcc", a collection of development tools and compilers compatible with Windows, Linux, and a host of other operating systems. Support for C, C++, and other languages is mostly included.

```
brew install gcc 
brew install wget
```

If this is the only need, then it should work.

Comment: Hello Deepak Yadav, thank you for your reply. When running "brew install gcc", I still get "Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  CompilerSelectionError: autoconf cannot be built with any available compilers.
Install GNU's GCC:
  brew install gcc<<<" 

Which sounds strange. It's looping me back to the same problem.
(edit: hit enter button too quick)

Comment: Run `xcode-select --install ` then `brew install gcc`. Hope this help